# How to Conditionally Ignore a Substring With Regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I require a regular expression which matches the bold in String 1 and String 2 to Group 1.

> String 1:
>
> Downloads/**Sherlock** - Season
> 03/Sherlock.S03E02.SD.DVD-The.Sign.of.Three.mkv
>
> String 2:
>
> Downloads/[ www.TorrentDay.com ] -
> **Spy**.2011.S01E01.HDTV.XviD-W4F/spy.avi

How do I match both of the intended substrings, ignoring that part I don't want, in the best way?

If another road needs to be taken from scratch, I'm all ears.

I am using Python3.

**Edit:**

From messy regex experiment to requirements specification

Comment: Your regex  doesn't capture *Sherlock* in String 1 separately. It captures entire *Downloads/Sherlock -* https://regex101.com/r/wwaHUB/1

Comment: You'd better talk about your requirements. Regex seems a mess.

Comment: You are right, it was very messy. I've edited my post to talking about the requirements.

Comment: @PointoSenshi was the answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

I prepared this regex, before you updated your question:

```
(?<=\/)(?|.*-\s*(.+)[.]\d{2,4}[.]|(.+)\s*-\s*Season\s\d?\d\/).*[.\s]?S(\d?\d)[.\s]?E(\d?\d)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/AtPkCt/1)

Sample Code:

```
import regex as re    
regex = r"(?<=\/)(?|.*-\s*(.+)[.]\d{2,4}[.]|(.+)\s*-\s*Season\s\d?\d\/).*[.\s]?S(\d?\d)[.\s]?E(\d?\d)"    
test_str = ("Downloads/Sherlock - Season 03/Sherlock.S03E02.SD.DVD-The.Sign.of.Three.mkv\n"
    "Downloads/[ www.TorrentDay.com ] - Spy.2011.S01E01.HDTV.XviD-W4F/spy.avi")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)    
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

PS: I use the alternative Python [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) package to take advantage of the PCRE features, specifically `?|` [Branch Reset Groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html).